# rs.next looping through all values and I need it to loop through each value and kickout with if statement

Tags: java

// it keeps on looping through all values and I need it to loop through each value and kick out with the if statement

```
while(rs.next())  {
    String userName2 = rs.getString("username");
    String passWord2 = rs.getString("password");
    String UserPass3 = userName2 + passWord2;

    if(UserPass1.equalsIgnoreCase(UserPass3)) {
        out.println("<br><br><br><b><i>Welcome " + UserPass3 + " to NetDesignAmerica!!</i></b>");
    }
    else {
        out.println("<br><br><br><b><i>Sorry " + UserPass1 + " didnt match any of our records</i></b>" );
    }
}
```

Comment: So `userPass3` contains the user ID ***and password*** in cleartext, and you are going to display that on the web page?  Are you sure?

Comment: What is `rs`? What is "kickout"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `break` statement inside the `if` condition. This will get you out of the `while` loop after executing the `if` block.

Replace:

```
 if(UserPass1.equalsIgnoreCase(UserPass3)) {
   out.println("<br><br><br><b><i>Welcome " + UserPass3 + " to NetDesignAmerica!!</i></b>");
 }
```

With:

```
if(UserPass1.equalsIgnoreCase(UserPass3)) {
   out.println("<br><br><br><b><i>Welcome " + UserPass3 + " to NetDesignAmerica!!</i></b>");
   break;
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comments, it seems you want something like this:

```
int flag = 0;
while(rs.next())  {
    String userName2 = rs.getString("username");
    String passWord2 = rs.getString("password");
    String UserPass3 = userName2 + passWord2;

    if(UserPass1.equalsIgnoreCase(UserPass3)) {
        out.println("<br><br><br><b><i>Welcome " + UserPass3 + " to NetDesignAmerica!!</i></b>");
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag == 0) {
    out.println("<br><br><br><b><i>Sorry " + UserPass1 + " didnt match any of our records</i></b>" );
}
```

Comment: it still is displaying all values and it says sorry it didnt match any of our records and it also says welcome to NetDesignAmerica because I have to records in my table...

Comment: I think there is more code that you need to show. `break` would only break from the `while` loop that you showed. If this is inside a loop(nested), then it will still go through each value.

Comment: there is no other while loops the while(rs.next()) is the only loop besides the if statements

Comment: So you want to end the loop in both conditions whether `UserPass1.equalsIgnoreCase(UserPass3)` is true or false?

Comment: no I want to end the loop if it is either true or false, if it is true then I need it to kick out, if it is false, then I need it to kick out...

Comment: Then put break in both `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: On second thought, why do you even have a `while` loop then? Just have `if(rs.next())` instead of `while(rs.next())`.

Comment: it is only displaying one value at a time now , since I used the if (rs.next()) statement, however I entered in one of my records "sallydoe" password "123456" and it said sorry sallydoe didnt match any of our records...

Comment: because I am pretty sure it is not reaching that second value in my table with just one rs.next() statement, I need a loop I am pretty sure... but I cant get it to cycle through each rs.next() and kickout when it matches the if statement....

Comment: Try the code in my edited answer. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes!!  it worked, thank you very much! I really appreciate it... if I run into anymore problems I will post my question on here..

Comment: @noeway if this answer helped you, you can click the big check mark beside the answer to accept it.

Comment: where is the check mark I dont see it , how do you get to it from the question page?

Comment: @noeway http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ok I clicked the check mark, did it register with you yet? again thanks

Comment: Sure, no problem. If you see a green check mark, then it did.